# Java remover um item dentro de uma lista encadeada Simples

Tags: java, lista-encadeada

Estou tendo dificuldades em gerar um código para remover um item de uma determinada posição em uma lista encadeada, isso nao eh um ArrayList, e sim uma lista encadeada, para isso estou criando um método conforme abaixo:

```
public Object remove(int posicao){
```

Sei que a criação é parecida com a do método na posição, mas não estou conseguindo desenvolver o método na forma de remover itens no meio da lista.

```
package slist;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SList {

private SListNode head;
  private int tamanho;

  public SList() {
    tamanho = 0;
    head = null;
  }

  public boolean eVazio() {
    return tamanho == 0;
  }

  public int length() {
    return tamanho;
  }

  public void insereAntes(Object obj) {
    head = new SListNode(obj, head);
    tamanho++;
  }

  public void insereApos(Object obj) {
    if (head == null) {
      head = new SListNode(obj);
    } else {
      SListNode no = head;
      while (no.next != null) {
        no = no.next;
      }
      no.next = new SListNode(obj);
    }
    tamanho++;
  }

  public Object naPosicao(int posicao) {
    SListNode noAtual;

    if ((posicao < 1) || (head == null)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      noAtual = head;
      while (posicao > 1) {
        noAtual = noAtual.next;
        if (noAtual == null) {
          return null;
        }
        posicao--;
      }
      return noAtual.item;
    }
  } 

  public Object remove(int posicao){

}  

  public String toString() {
    int i;
    Object obj;
    String res = "[  ";

    SListNode atual = head;

    while (atual != null) {
      obj = atual.item;
      res = res + obj.toString() + "  ";
      atual = atual.next;
    }
    res = res + "]";
    return res;
  }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
    SList lst1 = new SList();
    SList lst2 = new SList();
    int escolha;
    Scanner opcao = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("Menu de opcoes \n"
        + "1 - Coloca na lista \n"
        + "2 - Mostra na Lista \n"
        + "3 - Listar conteudo de determinada posicao\n"
        + "4 - Remover conteudo de determinada posicao \n");

        escolha = opcao.nextInt();

            switch (escolha) {
                case 1: System.out.println(" Diga o nome do aluno");
                opcao.nextLine();
                String item = opcao.nextLine();
                    lst1.insereApos(item);
                    break;
                case 2: System.out.println("Listando os nomes da lista\n"
                                            + lst1.toString());
                    break;
                case 3: System.out.println("informe a posicao desejada");
                    int esc = opcao.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Objeto na posicao " + esc + " " + lst1.naPosicao(esc));
                case 4:     


            }
    } while (escolha <=4);
  }
}
```

E aqui a Class SListNode

```
package slist;

public class SListNode {
  Object item;
  SListNode next;

  SListNode(Object obj) {
    item = obj;
    next = null;
  }

  SListNode(Object obj, SListNode next) {
    item = obj;
    this.next = next;
  }

}
```

Comment: Só um comentário, se esta a utilizar java deveria utilizar as estruturas que ele dispõe que estão otimizadas para uma melhor performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só tem que fazer trocar a ligação removendo o atual e passar o próximo do atual ao predecessor.

**A lógica é bastante simples:**

> **Lista**
>
> {Nó-Anterior} -> {Nó a ser Excluído} -> {Nó posterior ao excluído}
>
> **Operação a ser feita:**
>
> {Nó Anterior}.next = {Nó posterior ao excluído}

Para isso modifiquei o seu método `Object naPosicao()` para retornar um nó da lista:

```
public SListNode getNo(int posicao) { //retorna direto um nó e não um objeto
    SListNode noAtual;

    if ((posicao < 1) || (head == null)) {
        return null;
    } else {
        noAtual = head;
        while (posicao > 1) {
            noAtual = noAtual.next;
            if (noAtual == null) {
                return null;
            }
            posicao--;
        }
        return noAtual; // única mudança real no método.
    }
}
```

Agora que já consegue obter os nós com esse método basta usá-lo para fazer a lógica que descrevi antes:

```
public void remove(int posicao) {
    try{
        SListNode predecessor = getNo(posicao - 1);
        SListNode excluido = predecessor.next;
        predecessor.next = excluido.next;
        excluido = null;  // Para tentar facilitar a exclusão para o garbage collector
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Repare que não excluí o objeto, pois isso não é possível fazer diretamente em Java, mas ao definir `excluido = null;` eu elimino as referências para que o mesmo seja pego (de uma forma *mais explícita*) pelo o garbage collector. É um passo não necessário, visto que a referência desaperecerá do programa apés esse método ser chamado, mas deixa claro que não se pretende utilizar o nó excluído novamente.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado pela ajuda!